# ajax with jsp and mysql : java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname", "root", "root");
             st = con.createStatement();
             rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT `lastname` FROM `names` WHERE `firstname`='"+first+"' &&  company like '"+comp+"%'");
```

one of the answers said to run this command on console :

**GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;**

can anyone please tell me how to run it with basic steps

I am using eclipse with xampp server and mysql-connector-XXX.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run that command on your Mac OSX console or Windows CMD, you first must type in: "mysql" to enter the "console of your database", so to speak. Then you can copy paste that bolded line in your question once you're logged into Mysql.